# How to I use all user info in sessions

Tags: php, session

How do I use things like $email and $image in sessions when I only use username and password to log ind. It seems like I only can use $username ()

I don't know how to collect the last user info to sessions?

server.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

// variable declaration
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 
$_SESSION['success'] = "";


// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect('Localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

    $uploaddir = 'assets/images/users/';
    $image = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $image);
```

index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: pages-login.php');
}

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: pages-login.php");
}

?>

...

<?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
                                        <div class="success" >
                                            <h3>
                                                <?php 
                                                    echo $_SESSION['success']; 
                                                    unset($_SESSION['success']);
                                                ?>
                                            </h3>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif ?>

                                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">

                                            <!-- logged in user information -->
                                            <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
                                                <p>Hej <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>! </strong>Velkommen til Kommandocentralen</p>
                                            <?php endif ?>

                                            <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>!

                                        </li>
                                    </ol>
```

I can not get it to give $email the same way it gives me $username.

I cut out a lot of the code between the php-bits

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Could you explain a bit because from what you explained, `$email`, `$image` and `$username` are all variables, so why did you create them?

Comment: I get the variables from a registre form, and when I want to use them I can only use $username.

if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
// receive all input values from form
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
$password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
$password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

$uploaddir = 'assets/images/users/';
$image = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $image);

Comment: Could your update your question with the results of the output from the code `print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: Have I done like you mean?

Comment: That too but I also want to see what information is being passed when you submit the form so inside the `if (isset($_POST['reg_user']))` put `print_r($_POST)` and also put the results that is shown on the page in your question.

Comment: I just added some more¨

Comment: I was not referring to your source code. What I want to check is if all the values from the form fields are being submitted and to do that, the same way you process the form, I would like you to add the code `print_r($_POST)` to your code, submit the form and the new results that show up, include it here. Do you understand?

Comment: Sorry but where is it you would like me to add the code? after the form?

Comment: After you check to see if the form was submitted (`if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) { // ... here ... }`).

Comment: This was returned:

Array ( [username] => Mathias Rue6 [email] => mathias@mathiasrue.dk [password_1] => 12345 [password_2] => 12345 [MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 40000 [reg_user] => ) 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/mathiasrue.dk/Rue/includes/server.php:17) in /var/www/mathiasrue.dk/Rue/includes/server.php on line 48

Comment: ok, then when you try to use the `$email` variable, what happens?

Comment: When I in the code write the following I only get the exclamation point :  <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>!

Comment: Where do you set the session variable for the email: `$_SESSION['email'] = $email;`?

Comment: No where - I thought it was set with session_start(); - Where should it be?

Comment: No, `session_start();` does not automatically set that data. I see you have a session data called `success` (`$_SESSION['success']`). Where in your code do you se that data?

Comment: In the file server.php (I think)

Comment: Now I'm a bit more confused but tell me, Are you trying to create a system where users can register, you store the information in a database and then the user can login using their username and password that they registered with and once they are logged in you want to be able to access the email and other data?

Comment: I'm sorry - as you can see I'm new to php. But you I want use the data when the user is logged in. I want to show profile image and write things like welcome back, $username - your email is $email.

Comment: I see this tutorial page (http://codewithawa.com/posts/complete-user-registration-system-using-php-and-mysql-database) seems to be what you may have been following as the code ther is very similar to yours. Revise the tutorial and, see if you are following the same pattern and if there is anything you do not understand, do ask.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try this 

Comment: I just went through the tut, and it is pretty much the same as I had, but I still have the same issue with accessing $email in the index-php page. I can only access $username. How to do I add $email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the same guidlines of the tutorial, on the `server.php` page, when the user registers or login, after the line that says `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`, you can add other session data after that as follows:

When registering the user:

```
// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    ...
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    ...
}
```

When the user logs in:

```
// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    ...
    $row = $results->fetch_array();

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
    ...
}
```

For the user login, `$results[0]['email']`, references the `email` column of your database table so whichever data you want to make available, will need to use the same as is in the tabla. For example you would reference the `image` column as `$results[0]['image']`.

All other session variables can be set following the above pattern.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't. I still doesn't work. I can't get email to show in the index.php. And I got an error because of: $_SESSION['email'] = $results[0]['email'];

Comment: @Rue, Sorry I forgot part of the code. Check the answer now and let me know.

Comment: Can you tell me how my image column I my database should look for it to save my images?

$uploaddir = 'assets/images/users/';
    $image = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $image);

Comment: @Rue What you would do is create a column of type VARCHAR(255) or TEXT which would store the name of the image file. So you could have for example, `$image_name = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']`, and you would store that value in the database. Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

yes it worked - it stored the image in the folder I requested. but now I'm not sure how to show it?

```
    // REGISTER USER
...
$uploaddir = 'assets/images/users/';
$image = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $image);
...
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['userfile'] = $image;
...

    // LOGIN USER
...
$row = $results->fetch_array();
...
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
$_SESSION['userfile'] = $row['userfile'];
...
```

And then in the index.php

```
...    
<img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['userfile']; ?>" />
...
```

But nothing shows - can you se what my error is?